# Javascript window.location is getting called again and again IE-8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies, dom-events

I am checking, getting and setting a cookie to trace the last visited page. And to do this I am calling a Javascript `onload`. Issue is when I execute this js, it refreshes again and again,  very much like a even on mouse movement, but I am not having any event other than `onload`.

Here is my js:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    
    window.onload = function(event){        
        var currentPage = window.location.href;
        var lastVisited = getCookie('udis');
        var sessionId= getCookie('udisSession');
        if(lastVisited === null || lastVisited === undefined){
            setCookie("udis", currentPage, 365);
            lastVisited = getCookie('udis');
        }
        if(sessionId === null || sessionId === undefined){
            setSessionCookie('udisSession');
            if(lastVisited !== currentPage){
                window.location.href = lastVisited;         
            }           
        }
        setCookie("udis", currentPage, 365);
        updateBreadCrumb();
    }
        
        function getCookie(c_name) {
            var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
            for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++){
                x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
                x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
                if (x==c_name) {
                    return unescape(y);
                }
            }
        }
        function setSessionCookie(c_name){
        document.cookie=c_name + "=" + 'testSession'+'; expires=; path=/';
    }
        
        function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
            var exdate=new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";   expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }
      

    //]]>
    </script>
```

**The above code works flawlessly in Firefox but in IE-8 it's causing the page to reload again and again.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting a cookie, you need a space after the semicolon.  You also need an expiration date.  If you want to make a cookie that expires when the browser closes, then remove the expiration date clause.

```
function setSessionCookie(c_name){
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + 'testSession'+'; path=/';
}
```

I suggest you use the functions from [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html):

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Instead of using `setSessionCookie(c_name)`, you could use `createCookie(c_name, 'testSession');`

Comment: @Rachel: You did't give it an expiration date, so it expired right away.

Comment: I am actually making 2 cookies. 'udis' and 'udisSession'. first cookie (udis) is having a expiration date. But second cookie is a session cookie that is the reason I didn't set any expiration date.

Comment: @Rachel: To make a cookie expire when the browser is closed, remove the `expires=` clause.

Comment: @Rocket: It's working now. Other than adding space after semicolon and removing the "expire=" clause; I didn't make any change. I didn't get the actual cause.

Comment: @Rachel: That was the cause.  You need a space after the semicolon for the cookie to set correctly.  Also `expire=;` told it to expire right away, so it was never set.

Comment: @Rocket: Thanks. Now I am getting it. But FF was ok with that. Wonder!

Comment: @Rachel: IE can sometimes be more strict than other browsers.